# Contradictions against including ComObj.hpp for non-COM programs?

Tags: com, compiler-warnings, precompiled-headers, c++builder-6

I'm *fighting* against the last compiler warnings in a legacy project (**MS-COM** server, **C++-Builder 6**), and there are a few warnings left that I ignored previously, because they were raised from generated code for type library stubs (I quote the original German ones, and added a my translation):

> [C++ Warnung] utilcls.h(156): W8057 Parameter 'hr' wird nie verwendet.

(parameter 'hr' is never used)

> [C++ Warnung] utilcls.h(156): W8057 Parameter 'file' wird nie verwendet.

(parameter 'file' is never used)

I tried "solving it" with local options and pragmas - without success!

Today, I found that the [**proper solution** would be to include ComObj.hpp](http://borland.public.cppbuilder.ide.narkive.com/EeZmktz9/w8057-from-utilcls-h-line-156).

My project uses a set of precompiled headers (collected in one `precompiled.h`) starting with `#include <vcl.h>`. The warnings disappear if I **include `ComObj.hpp` before `vcl.h`**, but there are a lot of elements in the project (such as simple tool programs) that have nothing to do with MS-COM...

May it be **harmful to include `ComObj.hpp`** in an overall precompiled header set?

Comment: `// Hopefully we never get here`, that's certainly an appropriate comment.  The only thing that's clearly harmful is lousy error reporting.  Like not showing the *hr* value or not catching the exceptions that ComObj generates.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes that's right. And I definitely want to include `ComObj.hpp` in cases where `utilcls.h` is in use. But this header looks very COM specific, so I'm not sure if I be better use two different sets of precompiled headers...

Comment: `ComObj.hpp` conflicts with `winsock2.h` ... now I deepen my knowledge about precompiled headers ;)